# ValueError: Invalid template id: 'report_instalacion'

Tags: postgresql, xml, pdf, odoo

En el modulo de odoo que estoy desarrollando ya estoy haciendo la parte del reporte pero me esta marcando el error a la hora de imprimir les comparto la estructura del reporte segun esto todo esta correcto pero en la interfaz no esta reconociendo el id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>

<record id="action_report_instalacion" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Instalaciones</field>
    <field name="model">instalaciones</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">report_instalacion</field>
    <field name="report_file">report_instalacion</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">('Instalacion - %s' %(object.name))</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_instalaciones"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>

<template id="report_instalacion">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="object">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h1>Solicitud de Instalacion</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Empleado:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-field="object.empleado"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fecha:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-field="object.fecha"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Área:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-field="object.area"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Solicita:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-field="object.solicita"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Instalo:</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-field="object.instalo"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h2>Detalles de Instalacion</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>N° de serie</th>
                                        <th>Programa</th>
                                        <th>Comentarios</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr t-foreach="object.detalle_ids" t-as="detalle">
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="detalle.N_del_equipo"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="detalle.programa"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span t-field="detalle.comentarios"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

no entiendo porque no esta reconociendo el id del template como podria corregirlo o que podria hacer para que reconosca el id ya lo cambie por otro id estuve haciendo algunos cambios y nada funciona haga lo que haga sigue marcando el error de id template invalido como lo podria corregir para poder obtener el reporte